# Is there a way to capture all hibernate changes made, grouped by transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, hibernate-envers

I know I can create Pre/Post Insert/Update/Delete listeners, and I can record these events, but given that multiple transactions from multiple threads can be running at the same time, I'm not sure how I can group them together or identify that I've finished captured all of them.

I also know I can listen for when a transaction has been completed, but due to the above problem, I'm not sure how I can identify which changes were included in that transaction.

I am using envers already to create audits and using a custom revision class in order to add fields to the REVINFO record, if that helps.

Are there hibernate mechanics that I'm missing that would help with this?

EDIT:

What I'm actually trying to do:  After a transaction is complete (hopefully triggered by spring/hibernate/envers), iterate through all modifications made (i figured envers could provide this via its events, i'm happy to record these somewhere keyed by transaction ID), and then write a summary of what was changed to SQS.

Comment: Its a bit broad. What do you want to store? You could use a `ThreadLocal` bound to the current thread of execution to store data on a per thread basis. https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal. If this is webapp ensure you have cleared the ThreadLocal context as some suitable poiint in the request lifecycle as server may reuse threads from a pool.

Comment: That's definitely an option.  I guess what I was hoping for though was that if envers can write 100 audit records and group them to a single REV, is it possible for me to capture that REV in an insert/update/delete listener?

Comment: I updated the question with specifics of what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: An event listener has the old and new state of an object. Making a diff should be quite easy to do. But as you are already using envers why not utilize that instead? Or use something like JaVers to create a diff for the old and new version.

Comment: I have had a night to think about it and i think I was too fixated on getting spring/hibernate to group the changes into transactions for me (or provide a transaction id).  I think it's probably just best to stream the event changes somewhere and create my own batching/grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Envers, I would actually consider decoupling the report generation step entirely from the current application.  This gives you several advantages:

- Hibernate transactions won't involve any more steps than necessary, so they commit faster.
- Separation of concerns, your report generation is entirely independent.
- Retry logic becomes simply easy with a poll/push mechanism.

You can roll this all into one of course, but then I believe it becomes far more difficult to manage these points, but the decision is ultimately yours.

In the following explanation, I am going to assume the poll/push is done in a separate application.  The idea is that this separate application has the application entity mappings (or at least the ones of interest) included.

First, I would suggest that the revision-entity mapping for `REVINFO` also tracks modified entity types.  This is going to be super useful later on when generating the report because we can take the entity-type combined with the revision number and fetch revisions based on that.

Secondly, the separate application is designed to track the last revision number processed.  Every time the application's poll/push sequence fires, the application would see if there are any new revisions and if so, it would process them; otherwise it would wait and then poll again.

The overall idea of the concept would be:

1. Get all revision-entity instances since last revision number
2. Iterate each revision-entity and...

   - For each entity type modified in the revision, fetch the change by revision-entity rev number
   - For each entity type modified in the revision, fetch the revision prior
   - Perform a diff of the two java instances (using something like JaVers, etc)
3. Once all differences have been recorded, send report to SQS